# Replace Database field based on 2 different Table Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements

I need to update the table based on email matching condition and need to know SQL query that can solve this problem.

I have 2 tables "old_data" and "new_data"

```
Old_data contains around 60,000 records and fields "EMAIL"
New_data contains around 90,000 records and fields "EMAIL" "WHITE_NO"
```

Here is my logical condition I need help with.

```
Update * from Old_data, New_data SET New_data.WHITE_NO = 'true' WHERE old_data.EMAIL = New_data.EMAIL
```

What it will do is look for all emails in the old_data table and match them with all same emails into the new_data table and replace the WHITE_NO field values to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE new_data
       JOIN old_data
       ON new_data.EMAIL = old_data.EMAIL
SET    new_data.WHITE_NO = 'true';
```

OR

```
UPDATE new_data
SET new_data.WHITE_NO ='true'
WHERE new_data.EMAIL IN (SELECT EMAIL FROM old_data);
```

Comment: which one is faster way to run with more thein 1 million records ? i am using tableplus and phpmyadmin, both are slow and takes many hours

Comment: If both are slow you can try, but I'm not sure about the performance UPDATE new_data
       JOIN old_data
       ON new_data.EMAIL = old_data.EMAIL AND new_data.WHITE_NO !='true'
SET    new_data.WHITE_NO = 'true' limit 10000;  and make index on white_no.

Comment: i am using same statement that you written in comment. Here i am just using Inner join instead of join, but its also too slow

Comment: Can we give a try to make white_no field boolean instead of string and make it index. And execute query with limits.

Comment: There should be some primary key in table so that we can use it in where clause for executing query in parts

Answer (score 1):

You need an update with a join of the 2 tables:

```
update New_data
inner join old_data on old_data.EMAIL = New_data.EMAIL
set New_data.WHITE_NO = 'true'
```

Comment: I have tried it, but its too slow with above 1 million records, any solution to make it faster ?

Comment: An inner join is the way to do it and the only case that the performance would be improved is if there are indexes for both EMAIL columns.

Comment: can i set index with same statement you written above for email field on both databases ?

Comment: No, you need: `ALTER TABLE old_data ADD INDEX idx_old_email(EMAIL);` and `ALTER TABLE New_data ADD INDEX idx_new_email(EMAIL);`. You can find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: right, once i have created index for both email fields on both tables, how to call the indexes so they matched the values and set value to field ?

Comment: You don't have to call the indexes. The indexes are there so the column values can be found faster. So the join in the update statement will execute faster in most cases. Now execute the update statement.

Comment: i am getting this error when adding Alter table query

#1170 - BLOB column 'EMAIL' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: If the data type of the column EMAIL is BLOB, then you also need to specify the length of the index. But this would not help much. If the type is BLOB then you have the reason why the query takes too long.